# Is there a command for creating an app using cookiecutter-django?

Tags: django, cookiecutter-django

Once a Django project has been created using cookiecutter-django, is there a command like `python manage.py startapp <app_name>` to run instead of writing the new app from scratch?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Cookiecutter Django renders a Django project, and included with the files is a `manage.py` module. If you have Django installed, you can just call `python manage.py startapp <app_name>` and it should just work.

Comment: For some reason I was thinking that running the usual Django startapp wasn't enough and produced an architecture that doesn't fit with cookiecutter-django's architecture, and because of that there *had to be* an analog command somewhere... Looks that I was wrong ;)

Comment: I guess that I was thinking something like this: "`startapp` creates the app in the *first level*, the same directory where `manage.py` is.  Why not create the app in the `<project_name>/` level, where also the `users` app is?" Where am I wrong?

Comment: Before noticing the answer's author, I started digging around in the Two Scoops to verify this. It actually looks like it's meant to be on the top level. Cookiecutter Django adds a lot of functionality, but still on the same level as startproject. So, while you can add apps like you describe, the first level still remains the typical place.

Answer (score 32):

For the sake of completeness, I would like to add that project-specific apps should go into the *second level*, also when using Cookiecutter Django.

There is a [GitHub issue about this](https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django/issues/1725), where a project maintainer [explains the situation](https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django/issues/1725#issuecomment-407493176).

What you should do is the following:

> 1 - create the `<name-of-the-app>` app with `python manage.py startapp`
>   2 - move `<name-of-the-app>` directory to `<project_slug>` directory
>   3 - edit `<project_slug>/<name-of-the-app>/apps.py` and change `name = "<name-of-the-app>"` to `name = "<project_slug>.<name-of-the-app>"`
>   4 - add `"<project_slug>.<name-of-the-app>.apps.<NameOfTheAppConfigClass>"` to `LOCAL_APPS` in `config/settings/base.py`

Comment: Thanks that is very useful. For me, after having run `cookiecutter-django`, it wasn't even entirely clear if I _had_ to create an app right way, or if it had been somehow handled by the generation process.

Answer (score 2):

This is a good question as it is recommended to create a new app for every feature.Solution to this would be to call manage.py from the project directory. The call will look like this:

`python ../manage.py startapp <name_of_app>`

You would still need to rename your `app.py` and you need to add the app `settings/base.py` under local apps.